# Mysql Laravel Constraint PRIMARY KEY MYSQL don't allowed

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a simple table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dcp_type_discount` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `texte` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And when i try to insert in another table a column foreign key to this table don't allow to me to do that.

In my local environement It is working.
But in my server i have an error like that 
[image: console result]

I am using laravel migration system and that is my migration :

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dcp_type_discount', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('texte');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('dcp_doc_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('type_remise_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('type_remise_id')->references('id')->on('dcp_type_discount')->onDelete('cascade');

    });

    DB::table('dcp_type_discount')->insert(
        [
            [
                'code' => '%',
                'texte' => '%',
                'created_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ],
            [
                'code' => 'UNIT',
                'texte' => 'UNIT',
                'created_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]
        ]);
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('dcp_doc_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['type_remise_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('type_remise_id');

    });
    Schema::drop('dcp_type_discount');
}
```

I think that the problem is not just because of laravel, because i tried in my PhpMyAdmin and when i try to add mannually an index on colonne type_remise_id, in the foreign column all primary key appear without this one.

I don't know what happen?!

Thanks to everybody.

PS: that is the decribe of my item table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dcp_doc_item` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `line` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `material_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `document_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_wo_vat` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `vat` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `discount` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `net_price` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qte_col` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qte_colis` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_remise_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dcp_doc_item_material_id_foreign` (`material_id`),
  KEY `dcp_doc_item_document_id_foreign` (`document_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=85 ;
```

Comment: Could you publish "dcp_doc_item" DESC please ?.. Not really sure to clearly understand your issue.. Maybe datatypes of "type_remise_id" and "id" (dcp_type_discount table) are not the same..

Comment: I suggest you rework your migrations. If this is not yet a live system where you actually require to drop keys etc. because of an productive enviroment where you cannot simply drop your tables. The schema for the creation of dcp_doc_item should already set the foreign key. You also shouldnt insert data into the tables in your migrations.

Comment: @FrankProvost Because its master Data. What you say about my migration, i don't understand can you explain. Thanks

Comment: @Delphine The Type is integer like you can see in my migration int 10 it is the same that the primary key

Comment: Can you provide the migration instead of the desribe?

Comment: @FrankProvost The migration is in my post !

Comment: Well, parts of it, but not the actual creation of dcp_doc_item only some manipulating migrations